# Атрибут android:backgroundTint

Tags: android

Какую функцию выполняет атрибут View `android:backgroundTint`? В документации написано только

> Tint to apply to the background. May be a color value, in the form of
>   "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".

Т.е. оттенок, который применяется к фону виджета. Однако ведь мы можем также задать цвет фона через свойство

```
android:background="#rrggb"
```

При этом цвет, установленный через `android:background`, сразу виден, а при установке цвета через `android:backgroundTint` визуальных изменений нет (или по крайней мере, сразу они не заметны). Для чего тогда нужен этот атрибут?

Comment: я вешал backgroundTint на button. изменения были. Она вроде как готовый xml равномерно раскрашивает. То есть если кнопка из разных оттенков, то этот цвет применяется ко всему. Могу ошибаться конечно. Есть еще foregroundTint. В старых версиях не поддерживаются

Comment: С картинками показано что и зачем: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471009/what-is-the-difference-between-background-backgroundtint-backgroundtintmode-at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К примеру возьмем какой-нибудь `EditText`, который имеет свой `background`, если вы зададите ему `android:background="#rrggb"` он покрасится сплошным цветом, а если `android:backgroundTint`, то `background` останется прежним, только изменит цвет.